# Can you rename the Django GeoManager object instance?

Tags: postgis, geodjango

Is it possible to change the name of the GeoManager object from "objects" to something like "geo_objects"?  The way I've done it in the code below is supposed to be the default way to configure your model if you're using GIS.  I would think that you could so long as you always call the GeoManager using the new name.  However, I don't see this GeoManager object instance used elsewhere in my model so I'm not sure if it's possible to change the name if I can't see where it's being referenced.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class PersonalProfile(CommonProfileInfo):
    # ...
    # GeoDjango-specific fields 
    home_point = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    objects = models.GeoManager()   # <= Change name of "objects"?
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, you can name the GeoManager attribute in your class anyway you want. However, I would not recommend it. Here are a few thoughts on what it means if you don't call it "objects".

From the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geomanager):

> In order to conduct geographic queries, each geographic model requires
>   a GeoManager model manager. This manager allows for the proper SQL
>   construction for geographic queries; thus, without it, all geographic
>   filters will fail.

As the documentation further explains, the GeoManager is needed if you want to conduct geographic queries, such as

```
qs = Address.objects.filter(zipcode__poly__contains='POINT(-104.590948 38.319914)')
```

Now by default, Django uses the "objects" attribute of models to make queries. So for instancce, in the Admin pages, the querysets that are displayed will be managed through the manager called "objects", similar to the code snippet above.

If you don't use the GeoManager for the "objects" attribute, you might run into trouble in some parts of your Django app, basically whenever Django would try to do spatial queries.

On you own application code however, you will be able to call the GeoManager through your custom attribute name. So if you call it "objects_geo", you can use it through

```
qs = Address.objects_geo.filter(zipcode__poly__contains='POINT(-104.590948 38.319914)')
```

If your main reason for wanting to call this differently is that you are writing a custom manager, you could either give your cusom manager a different name (i.e. call the GeoManager "objects", and yours "objects_custom") or subclass from GeoManager. If you make your custom manager a subclass of GeoManager, you can use your custom one in the "objects" attribute while maintaining the geoquery functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to matter what you name the variable that you assign models.GeoManager to.  I changed it to "objects_geo" and it didn't appear to affect my GeoDjango queries.  I was  concerned about this because I needed to create another custom manager for the model in question and I was worried that the two might conflict with each other.  I was also confused because I didn't know if this code would cause the GeoManager manage to override the default Django manager.  It does but after looking at both managers in the Python shell, it appears that GeoManager's manager is the same as the default manager with some additional geo-specific methods added.